a question in python django about FileField's attr_class
enter image description here
I was reading the Django source code and came across a question. In the image above, there is an attribute called attr_class in FileField. According to the Django official documentation, when attr_class is specified, FileField returns an instance of attr_class. However, I am curious about the specific functionality of the attr_class.
I have already searched for attr_class in PyCharm, but I could not find any other usage. I have also searched online, but apart from the Django documentation, there are no other explanations available, and the official documentation does not address my question. I would greatly appreciate if someone could assist me with this. Thank you in advance.
